# Study the uniformly convergence of function:

Tags: real-analysis

I would like to study the convergence of next funcion:

$$f_n(x)= \frac {x}{n}\space if \space 0\leq x\leq n $$ $$f_n(x)=1\space if \space x>n$$
I don't know how to do it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For each $x$  $f(x)=\frac x n$ whenever $n >x$ so $f_n(x) \to 0$, If the convergence is uniform then $f_n (n)$ must tend to $0$ but $f_n(n)=1$ so the convergence is not uniform.

Details: Let $0 <\epsilon <1$.  By definition if $f_n \to 0$ uniformly then given $\epsilon >0$ there exist $n_0$ such that $|f_n(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x$ whenver $n \geq n_0$. We can put $x=n$ here as long as $n \geq n_0$. But then you get $1 <\epsilon$

Answer (score 0):

0) $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f_n(x)= 0$ for $x \in [0,1$].

Pointwise convergence.

1) $s:=$

$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sup ${$f_n(x)| x \in [0,\infty]$} $=1$.

Not uniformly convergent (since $s \not =0$).